# How I can start mongodb automatically?

Tags: macos, launchd, services

I'm doing like here is described

http://hunterford.me/mongodb-startup-item/

but my file called different and path is here `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist`. and mongo is starting well, but after system restart i have go through two last command again

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mongo.mongod.plist
sudo launchctl start org.mongo.mongod
```

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from configuring MongoDB exactly the same way as described in the linked article?

Comment: dead link, would you please document the process of starting automatically mongodb process please ? This is one of the first questions that appear in google when searching for such keywords ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use sudo to load it, the plist file may be owned by root. Launchd will only automatically load agents that *you* own from ~/Library/LaunchAgents, where it will load agents owned by root from /Library/LaunchAgents.

You can do `ls -l ~/Library/LaunchAgents` to view the ownership of the plist. If you actually want it to run under your user account, you can change it's ownership:

```
sudo chown `whoami` ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

However, if you need to run mongod as root, you should leave the plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons

Comment: thank you very much this is exactly what i'm looking for.